# How to change a normal column to "computed" column

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a table in MSSQL server 2008. I would like to change one of the column in that table to computed column. Could somebody tell me how do I do that ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Preserve [the old data:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx)

```
EXEC sp_rename 'MyTable.OldCol', 'RenamedOldCol', 'COLUMN';
```

Add [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD ComputedCol AS (some expression);
```

Then, [when you're happy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN RenamedOldCol;
```