# SQL Server Alter normal column to Persisted Computed Column

Tags: sql-server-2012, calculated-columns

How do I alter an existing normal column to Persisted computed column in SQL Server 2012?

For 2008 version, I found the following link which states to Add new computed column and drop the normal column. Is there a way to do this without dropping the column?

[How to change a normal column to "computed" column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767760/how-to-change-a-normal-column-to-computed-column)

Comment: Why would you want to NOT drop the original column? The values are going to be computed anyway when you create the new column, yes?